# How to force Solr 6 to merge Segments

Tags: search, indexing, solr, segments

For comparison purposes I need to merge segments of a Solr core to only one segment. Changing the solrconfig by playing with following lines

```xml
<mergePolicyFactory class="org.apache.solr.index.TieredMergePolicyFactory">
  <int name="maxMergeAtOnce">10</int>
  <int name="segmentsPerTier">10</int>
</mergePolicyFactory>
```

won't take any effect rather than bad exceptions.

Comment: Remember that any mergePolicy definition has to live inside `indexConfig`. And call optimize on the index to force a possible merge.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for your answers, executing following command will force merge to an amount of segments of your choosing: "http://FOO:8983/solr/BAR/update?optimize=true&maxSegments=1&waitFlush=false"